# Spring Boot failure with REST Service

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, pojo

I am developing an application in Spring Boot Rest and encountering the below issue while hitting the service -

```
<deliveryCalendarResponse>
  <retCode>-1</retCode>
  <retReason>Invalid Start date. Enter valid date in yyyy-MM-dd format</retReason>
  <timeSlotList/>
</deliveryCalendarResponse>
```

This message would only come when the start date is null in the request. I am passing below JSON as the request -

```
{
    "deliveryCalendarRequest": {
        "zip": "60169",
        "clientcode": "",
        "timeWindow": "ALL",
        "cubes": 1000,
        "servicetime": 3600,
        "startDate": "2017-01-13",
        "address": "address",
        "city": "city",
        "state": "state"
    }
}
```

JSON is mapped to POJO -

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "zip",
    "clientcode",
    "ehdsrsv",
    "timeWindow",
    "cubes",
    "servicetime",
    "startDate",
    "address",
    "city",
    "state"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "deliveryCalendarRequest")
public class DeliveryCalendarRequest {

    public String zip;
    public String clientcode;
    public String ehdsrsv;
    public String timeWindow;
    public double cubes;
    public long servicetime;
    public String startDate;
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public String state;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the zip property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the zip property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setZip(String value) {
        this.zip = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the clientcode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getClientcode() {
        return clientcode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the clientcode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setClientcode(String value) {
        this.clientcode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ehdsrsv property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEhdsrsv() {
        return ehdsrsv;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the ehdsrsv property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEhdsrsv(String value) {
        this.ehdsrsv = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the timeWindow property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTimeWindow() {
        return timeWindow;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the timeWindow property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTimeWindow(String value) {
        this.timeWindow = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the cubes property.
     * 
     */
    public double getCubes() {
        return cubes;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the cubes property.
     * 
     */
    public void setCubes(double value) {
        this.cubes = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the servicetime property.
     * 
     */
    public long getServicetime() {
        return servicetime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the servicetime property.
     * 
     */
    public void setServicetime(long value) {
        this.servicetime = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the startDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the startDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setStartDate(String value) {
        this.startDate = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the address property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the address property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAddress(String value) {
        this.address = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the city property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the city property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCity(String value) {
        this.city = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the state property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the state property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setState(String value) {
        this.state = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeliveryCalendarRequest [zip=" + zip + ", clientcode=" + clientcode + ", ehdsrsv=" + ehdsrsv
                + ", timeWindow=" + timeWindow + ", cubes=" + cubes + ", servicetime=" + servicetime + ", startDate="
                + startDate + ", address=" + address + ", city=" + city + ", state=" + state + "]";
    }

}
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shc.ecom.urs</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>URS</name>
    <description>URS Project for universal reservation, handling different reservation source systems</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <!-- <org.springframework.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> -->
        <!-- <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> -->
        <!--<spring.data.cassandra.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.data.cassandra.version> -->
        <spring.data.cassandra.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring.data.cassandra.version>
        <jersey.version>1.14</jersey.version>
        <maven.antrun.plugin.version>1.7</maven.antrun.plugin.version>
        <dbcpVersion>1.4</dbcpVersion>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <axis2.version>1.5.4</axis2.version>
    </properties>
    <!--Changed spring core jar version to 4.1.4.RELEASE -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
 -->        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- In memory database used by spring-boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->       



        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.4</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version> -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added for serializing into JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.shc.orderservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>orderservice-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.shc.ecom.fastpromise</groupId>
            <artifactId>FPSDataPersistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>create-war</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>prod/*.*</exclude>
                            <exclude>prodch3/*.*</exclude>
                            <exclude>qa/*.*</exclude>
                            <exclude>stress/*.*</exclude>
                            <exclude>dev/*.*</exclude>
                            <exclude>dev-spring-boot/*.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                                <version>2.17</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <groups>test</groups>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            <formats>
                                <format>html</format>
                                <format>xml</format>
                            </formats>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Normally, we take off the dependency report, saves time. -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>libs-release</name>
            <url>http://obuartifactoryvip.prod.ch3.s.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots />
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>http://obuartifactoryvip.prod.ch3.s.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>plugins-release</name>
            <url>http://obuartifactoryvip.prod.ch3.s.com/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots />
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
            <url>http://obuartifactoryvip.prod.ch3.s.com/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

This request works fine I pass it in the below fashion -

```
{
        "zip": "60169",
        "clientcode": "",
        "timeWindow": "ALL",
        "cubes": 1000,
        "servicetime": 3600,
        "startDate": "2017-01-13",
        "address": "address",
        "city": "city",
        "state": "state"
}
```

I guess its @XmlRootElement(name = "deliveryCalendarRequest") which is actually not working hence JSON isn't resolved. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The JSON in the first sample is wrong the second is the correct one. You don't need the root element in the JSON version only XML requires it. The JSON is directly mapped to the object present in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you don't need to specify  the name of the object, JSON know that there is an object inside {}. it doesn't need to know its name nor its type.

So this object is correct:

```
{
        "zip": "60169",
        "clientcode": "",
        "timeWindow": "ALL",
        "deliveryCalendarRequestcubes": 1000,
        "servicetime": 3600,
        "startDate": "2017-01-13",
        "address": "address",
        "city": "city",
        "state": "state"
}
```

The first example that you used, is for case when the object has a property with a name "**deliveryCalendarRequest**", something like this:

```
class MyObject{
    DeliveryCalendarRequest deliveryCalendarRequest;//property
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of this. The second request works absolutely fine when I don't use spring boot. There is something getting messed up in the JSON to Java Object conversion logic because of the spring boot web dependency. I guess this needs to be resolved and codehaus needs to be used for converting.